# How to handle large data set in web browser?

Tags: javascript, visualization, bigdata

I am working on a web application which is dealing with bigdata visualization. I am using highcharts for visualization of data. I have tried all of the possible methods proposed by highcharts.

Now there is one work around in my mind is to request more memory from system for my web page. But I don't know how is it possible by using javascript in browsers.

please help me to find any best solution.

Comment: So you tried the data grouping which highcharts provides for this issue?

Comment: @K.Rohde I have used the data grouping. it works to some extent but also deshape my graph.

Answer (score 0):

What I am proposing here is not a full answer but a set of questions, you should ask yourself, before going with this or that solution.

- What is the size of the data?

  - Are we talking about hundreds, thousands or millions data point?
- Can you aggregate the data points?

  - If you struggle to efficiently aggregate on the client-side, do it server side (and cache/memoize the results where possible). Do you have access to the server side code?
- Do you need all the data at first load?

  - If no, find out what you need at first, then load the rest on demand.
- Is the animation interactive?

  - If so, consider to remove non essential interactions. If the visualization is static just create the visualization server-side where possible.
- What are the target browsers?

  - Study your user base browser and focus on the features they provide. If you don't have to support older browser you can focus on some speedups that the Web API provides you.
- Do you have multiple visualization in the page?

  - Consider to split heavy dataviz into multiple views.

This list of questions is not exhaustive, but it is a starting point. If anybody has better questions to add just comment here and I'll update.